# Play sound on Popup Box

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio, playback, playsound

I have this code below. What it does it displays a popup box whenever a new post is published (wordpress).

I would like to add a sound when the popup is displayed (triggered).

any ideas?

```
function siki_newposts_alert_ajax() {


        if(!empty($_POST['lastPostID']) && is_numeric($_POST['lastPostID'])) {

            $last = wp_get_recent_posts('1');
            $last_id = $last['0']['ID'];

            // Checks is opening links in new page is enabled
            $this->new_page ? $target = "target=\'_blank\'" : null;
            $this->color == 'notification' || $this->color == 'success' ? $colour = '#000' : $colour = '#FFF';

            $args = array(
                'numberposts' => 8,
                'offset' => 0,
                'category' => 0,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true );

            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

            echo "<script>\n";
            foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {

                /* Checking If Post Is In The Selected Categories */
                $cat_ids = get_the_category($recent['ID']);
                $publish = null;
                foreach($cat_ids as $cat_id) {
                    $pub = $cat_id->cat_ID;
                    if(in_array($pub, $this->categories) || in_array(0, $this->categories)) {
                        $publish = true;
                    }
                }
                /*****/

                if($recent['ID'] > $_POST['lastPostID'] && $publish) {
                    echo "generate('{$this->position}', '<strong><a style=\'color: {$colour};\' {$target} href=\'". get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ."\'>". addslashes($recent['post_title']) ."</a></strong>', '{$this->color}');\n";
                    echo "jQuery('div#sikiPostNum').html('{$last_id}');\n";
                }
            }
            echo "</script>\n";

        }

        /*
        * Custom Message
        */

        if(strlen($this->message) > 0 && $this->enable_cm && $this->cookie_set != 1) { // If message is set and enabled and new
            echo "<script>generate('{$this->position_cm}', '" . addslashes($this->message) . "', '{$this->color_cm}');</script>\n";
        }

    }
```

#### Any help would be much appreciated.

this is the view source code of the popup box

```
<div class="noty_bar" id="noty_121015168773080340"><div class="noty_message" style="font-size: 23px; line-height: 16px; text-align: justify; padding: 18px 30px 19px; width: auto; position: relative;"><span class="noty_text"><strong><a style="color: #FFF;" href="http://fortsatos.com/test-4/">test</a></strong></span><div class="siki_close" style="height: 16px; width: 16px; position: absolute; right: 7px; top: 7px; cursor: pointer; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,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&quot;) 0px 0px no-repeat scroll transparent;"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Add the Generated JS Code

Comment: what generated JS code?

Comment: script tag from your view source of the browser

Comment: Still dont get what you are talking about. what code should I add and how do i call it once the code above is triggered.